# Mono for Android Get table value from HTML website

Tags: c#, android, html

I'm using MonoDevelop (Android C#). Is there a way to get values from a HTML table from a specified URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for that, I made an android version, you can use it if you'd like.

You can get it here: https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0ByhrKT_k_LiXMVNhazJOUTkwZXc/edit

Comment: Thank you. How do I install this?

Comment: How do I install this, because there is no dll file?

Comment: Download all source files and compile in your MFA app.

Comment: Add all the files to my project? Tried that, but when I use:
var somethin = new  HtmlWeb ();
I get error that HtmlWeb cannot be found, even if I use HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.

Comment: I can't use HtmlWeb with this and if I use the standar version of HAP I get System.Xml error.

Comment: I'm sorry but you you will have to figure this out by yourself, well... if you want to actually learn something.